# For Hom and H*(X,Z) -- which fonts?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, math-operators, eulervm

This is a question about style, I am debating whether the math operator `\Hom` should be just

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
```

or if it should be some variant like

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{\mathnormal{Hom}}
```

The reason I'm even considering this is because I'm using the [`eulervm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eulervm) package. Also, when I write something like `cohomology $H^*(X,Z)$`, I do not use `\text{H}` but leave eulervm's mathematical font.

What do you think? Does the question make sense?

Here is a minimal example with the two choices.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
\[ \operatorname{Hom}(A,B) = 0 \]
\[ \mathnormal{Hom}(A,B) = 0 \]
\[ H^2(X,Z) = 0\]
\[ \operatorname{H}^2(X,Z) = 0\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some of this is just style choice but I'd use `\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}` for Hom and $H$ for H. Don't use `\text` for math (just use it for embedded bits of sentence) you could use `\mathrm{H}` but I think just using the math italic H is more usual. Note DeclareMathOperator gives `\Hom` the correct spacing not just the correct font, so is better than `\mathrm}{Hom}` (it is `\mathop{\mathrm{Hom}}` )

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I agree 100% when one does not use eulervm (I also changed \text to \operatorname, which is what I had originally intended, thanks). But with it, the fonts are drastically different, that's why I'm not so sure.

Comment: That's a stylistic decision that you can postpone until the end, provided you define macros for Hom and H.

Comment: @egreg: yes, it is.

Comment: IMHO it should be `\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}` and `\newcommand*\HH{\mathrm{H}}`, but it's a stylistic question rather than a TeXnical one -- I'm not sure if it's on-topic here...

Comment: it's more the lack of uniformity between Hom and H that bothers me. Maybe if one could use \mathnormal but tightening the spacing (so it looks more like a word rather than a mathematical expression).

Comment: @user125763 but for $\HH x$ you want no space, wheras for $\Hom x$ you wanna space, which is the reason why the two things should be coded differently. And for "`\mathnormal` but tightening the space", there's `\mathit`.

Comment: @yo': in euler mathit is different

Comment: I used to worry about questions like this and then I realised that it is not worth spending time on questions like this because the journals often override your choices.

Comment: @Andrew: that's a good point. on the other hand not all pdfs I write are meant for publication and often I prefer my own arxiv formatting than the journal one. (I was just curious about people's opinion)

Comment: Yes I agree: for internal documents I still go to too much effort to typeset them the way that I think they should be:)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an stylistic option (open to opinin-based answers) and not a really TeXnical issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both “Hom” and ”H” are similar to “log”, so they should be typeset in the text font (upright). However it's not a sin to have different opinions.

The most important thing is that you use macro definitions:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}% preferred
%\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{\mathnormal{Hom}}% with Euler type
\DeclareMathOperator{\HH}{H}% preferred
%\DeclareMathOperator{\HH}{\mathnormal{H}}% with Euler type
```

Not `\H`, because it's already reserved.

In the body of the document you'll use only `\Hom` and `\HH`. This way, you can delay the choice to the last moment.

Tightening the space in “Hom” in Euler type is not a choice: look at the following picture to see why.

[image]

Here's the source for the image

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{$H\mkern-#1mu o\mkern-#1mu m$\par}

\test{0}\test{0.2}\test{0.4}\test{0.6}\test{0.8}\test{1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why is tightening the space not an option?

Comment: @user125763 Did you try?

Comment: I don't know how

Comment: uhm, I guess it's a little improvement but not by much. Can I ask how you did it?

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of this answer is only to disagree with egreg that *H*<sub>*n*</sub>(*X*) should be typeset with an upright H. He claims that H is similar to log, and thus should be typeset similarly.

I believe instead that *H*<sub>*n*</sub> is a functor *F* just like *C*<sup>∞</sup>(*X*), *π*<sub>*n*</sub>(*X*), *Ω*<sup>*k*</sup>(*X*). All of these are written in italics, just like any other mathematical object, and *H*<sub>*n*</sub>(*X*) should be no different.

Comment: I think I agree. But if all functors should be typeset the same, then one would try and make the case that Hom is also a functor, hence it should be typeset (in case your rebuttal involves the sheaf Hom: I usually put an underline to denote that).